# Regex match optional character only if non-digit

Tags: regex

I am trying to match string a on which the first character is 1-9 and the next three characters are 0-9. **If** there are any additional characters the first additional character cannot be a digit. The full string cannot contain a @ character.

Strings that should pass

- 1234
- 1234 5678910
- 1234AB 12345678
- 1234stackoverflow
- 1234 stackoverflow

Should not pass

- 0123
- 123
- 12345
- 1235@6789
- ABCDEF

I came up with `^[1-9][0-9]{3}(\D)?` so far. But this passes `12345` as well.

Any help or guidance would be highly appreciated :)

Comment: try to change (\D) to (\D)+

Comment: try `^[1-9][0-9]{3}(\D|$)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this regex:

```
^[1-9][0-9]{3}([^@0-9][^@]*)?$
```

If I read your requirement correctly, matching strings should begin with 1-9, followed by 3 digits of any number, followed by anything provided it not be a number or at sign.  The `[^@0-9]` in the regex is a negative character class, matching any character which is non numeric and not the at symbol.

**Demo here:**

## Regex101

Comment: Couldn't edit my comment any longer. I was trying to say: 

**Thank you!** This is very close to what I am after. I realized I made a mistake in my requirement (and editedi my initial requirement). The matching strings should begin with 1-9, followed by 3 digits of any number, the first of any characters that may follow cannot be a digit or an @. Any characters thereafter can be anything but an @.

Comment: @Kaspar I updated my answer per your new requirements.

Comment: The `[^@0-9]?` part is not actually needed (it's redundant). And once you've removed it, I'd recommend changing `(|...)` to the more conventional `(...)?`.

Comment: @ruakh Check again.  I don't think it's redundant at all.  Post your regex if you think you can simplify this.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen: `^[1-9][0-9]{3}([^@0-9][^@]*)?$`

Comment: @ruakh Brilliant...just threw some rep at you.

Answer (score 1):

Use this `^[1-9][0-9]{3}(?:$|[^@\d][^@]*)`

```js
console.log('1234'.match(/^[1-9][0-9]{3}(?:$|[^@\d][^@]*)/));
console.log('1234 5678910'.match(/^[1-9][0-9]{3}(?:$|[^@\d][^@]*)/));
console.log('1234AB 12345678'.match(/^[1-9][0-9]{3}(?:$|[^@\d][^@]*)/));
console.log('1234stackoverflow'.match(/^[1-9][0-9]{3}(?:$|[^@\d][^@]*)/));
console.log('1234 stackoverflow'.match(/^[1-9][0-9]{3}(?:$|[^@\d][^@]*)/));
console.log('0123'.match(/^[1-9][0-9]{3}(?:$|[^@\d][^@]*)/));
console.log('123'.match(/^[1-9][0-9]{3}(?:$|[^@\d][^@]*)/));
console.log('12345'.match(/^[1-9][0-9]{3}(?:$|[^@\d][^@]*)/));
console.log('1235@6789'.match(/^[1-9][0-9]{3}(?:$|[^@\d][^@]*)/));
console.log('ABCDEF'.match(/^[1-9][0-9]{3}(?:$|[^@\d][^@]*)/));
```

Comment: I think you meant to say this: `^[1-9][0-9]{3}(?:$|[^@\d][^@]*$)` ... but I like this approach

Answer (score 0):

You can use this to get the correct matches:

```
/^[1-9]\d{3}[a-z]*$/i
```